# When writing a cookie using Javascript is it stored synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-cookie

Using `jQuery.cookie` here:

```
// Do stuff
$.cookie('something', 'yes', {
    domain: 'example.com',
    httpOnly: false,
    path: '/',
    expires: 10,
    secure: true
});
// Do other stuff...including using the cookie value right away
```

Do all browsers do the same thing?

Comment: `jQuery.cookie()` is a helper for [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), which is standardized and acts synchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes....

That is the point in that plugin -- to be able to use the value right away.

Comment: I'd more say the point of the plugin is that `document.cookie` can be a PITA on its own. But, either way, it is synchronous.

Comment: True true @JonathanLonowski